# How to re-use dynamic proto type cells in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a prototype cell in tableview and I want to re-use it to save memory.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    mytesttableviewcell *cell=[self.tbl dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
    cell.txt1.text=@"1234567890";
    cell.txt2.text=@"1234567890";
    return cell;
}
```

I couldn't find a way to do it.
Any ideas on how it can be done

Comment: you already did it , what's the problem ?

Comment: if 100 rows are loaded and scrolled ... will the cells get re-used ?

Comment: yes they'll ,,,,,, see complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie)`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instance method of `UITableView`

> A table view maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.